# How to resolve "Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded." while importing Python3 packages in R?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, virtualenv, pyenv

I want to import a certain library in my R code. While doing so, I studied certain links and found out that the following snippet is to be used:

```
library("reticulate")
use_python("/Users/aviral.s/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/may21/bin/python3")
source_python("athena/core/operation/jupyter_notebook.py")
```

As you can see, I am using a `virtualenv` -> `may21`. However, I am unable to import the above file's functions as I get an error:

```
Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) :
  Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
```

I tried another API `use_virtualenv("may21")` but in vain. I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932463/python-shared-library-not-found-in-r-reticulate) question but no response there.

My full code for performing the aforementioned action is:

```
> library("reticulate")
> use_python("/Users/aviral.s/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/may21/bin/python3")
> source_python("athena/core/operation/jupyter_notebook.py")
Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) :
  Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
> use_virtualenv("may21")
> source_python("athena/core/operation/jupyter_notebook.py")
Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) :
  Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
```

I expect to be able to use the Python3 APIs from my library. FYI, I have been able to import the same in the current virtualenv's Python3 shell.